# Use Raspberry Pi 4 to control Spotify?

Tags: pi-4, audio

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 to which I would like to add a small touchscreen. I would like to use it to control which music is played on my Sonos speakers. Is this possible?

To clarify, I do not wish to play music directly on the Raspberry Pi 4. But I would like to use it as a stand-alone controller for which music gets played on my Sonos speakers. I would like to be able to browser for artists and albums and then when I press play, I was the music to be played on devices connected to my Spotify account.

Comment: Look into mopidy:1) https://mopidy.com/ 2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=mopidy+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Thank you, looked into Mopidy and was told it would not work. Also had a look at Volumio.